# Inverse of $(U^H X U + D)$ where U is unitary, X and D diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse-problems

Given complex unitary matrix U,
and full rank diagonal matrices X and D with positive entries.
I'm looking for an efficient way to compute:
$(U^HXU+D)^{-1}$
The matrix inversion identity doesn't really help me since all the involved matrices are full rank.
If X was proportional to the identity matrix it would be problem solved :-)